# Add AHCI to initrd on CentOS7 after installation

Tags: centos, initrd

I built a complete CentOS7 system with lots of tools, preferences, etc in a VMware guest.  Once working fine I moved it to my physical server.  I managed to get grub2 installed and the bootloader now starts but drops into dracut shell.

I traced the problem down to AHCI.  If I disable AHCI in the BIOS then the system boots into CentOS7.  Can someone tell me how to add AHCI into the initrd on a running CentOS7 system?  (So I can re-enable AHCI in the BIOS)

I tried

```
dracut --add-drivers ahci -f /boot/initrd-$(uname -r).img $(uname -r)
```

and lsinitrd shows:

```
lsinitrd /boot/initramfs-3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64.img  | grep ahci
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root        63309 Feb 16 12:44 usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/ata/ahci.ko
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root        53813 Feb 16 12:44 usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/ata/libahci.ko

But it still won't boot with AHCI enabled in the BIOX
```

but it still won't boot with AHCI enabled in the BIOS

Comment: Are you using UEFI or CSM mode?

Comment: I'm using legacy (non-UEFI) mode.  Not sure what CSM is

Comment: A power off/on made it work!  I'm not sure if I should delete the question (or leave the dracut command for someone else stuck).  Just be sure to power cycle after making change in the BIOS.

Comment: CSM is Compatibility Support Module - a form of firmware where a BIOS compatibility layer sits on top of UEFI firmware.  AHCI support was sometimes problematic with CSM.